# Cannot access certain MS Server 2003 Active Directory users with Mountain Lion Server's Server App

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, openldap, osx-mountain-lion

The "magic triangle" is working perfectly for some users. Other users are invisible to the Mountain Lion OD master's Server App. Workgroup Manager can access all the users while Server App can't. Viewing permissions through the Server 2003 interface, it seems like the permissions of an invisible user and a visible one are same. I ran SetACL on the directories of the two users and it found no difference. How can I figure out the difference in the accounts/files that makes certain users invisible to Server App? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all the users' [Primary Group](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776334(v=ws.10).aspx) set to Domain Users?

Answer (score 0):

Our AD has 1000+ users. As it turns out, Server App could see all the users. It was hard to realize this for a couple of reasons: When viewing "Users from MyDomain", if I typed in a user's name, Server App would not recognize it. This behavior still occurs. It's only when I search under "All Users" that the name is recognized and labeled as a "User from MyDomain". I realized that Server App did recognize the account when I made a Local Network Group and tried adding a user. When I typed in the same user's name, Server App recognized the account. This whole issue is just the Server App behavior on Mountain Lion and accounts on a Windows Server 2003 AD server.